# Sort two inter-related arrays (players and scores) and print results?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to enter 3 players with 3 scores in using 2 arrays. 
For now I stuck, concerning the ranking; how to do ???

Small example:

```
Player 1 : Jeremy
Score Jeremy : 12

Player 2 : Julien
Score Julien : 18

Player 3 : Olivia
Score Olivia : 22
```

For the ranking we should have

```
The first => Olivia with 22 scores
The second => Julien with 18 scores
The third => Jeremy with 12 scores
```

Here is my code.

```
function main() {
    var players = new Array();
    var scores = new Array();

    for(i = 0; i<3; i++) {
        players[i] = prompt("Player " + (i+1) + " : ");
        scores[i] = prompt("Score " + (players[i]) + " : ");
    }
}
```

Thank you advance.

Comment: Why not using objects?You could have an object for each player containing their name and score.That way you could sort them using their ranking

Comment: why not store them in an array of objects? like `[ {name:'Jeremy', score:12 }, {name:'Olivia', score:22} ]` etc

Comment: @ Manos Kounelakis: thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting data into two arrays is probably not the easiest way to go, but assuming you have no choice, I would use a custom sorting function and an additional array containing indices related to the other arrays :

```js
main();

function main() {
  var players = new Array();
  var scores = new Array();
  var ranking = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    ranking[i] = i;
    players[i] = prompt("Player " + (i + 1) + " : ");
    scores[i] = prompt("Score " + (players[i]) + " : ");
  }
  indirectSort(3, ranking, scores);
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var ithPlayer = players[ranking[i]];
    var ithScore = scores[ranking[i]];
    console.log(ithPlayer, ithScore);
  }
}

function indirectSort (n, toBeSorted, toBeCompared) {
  for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
      var a = toBeCompared[toBeSorted[j]];
      var b = toBeCompared[toBeSorted[i]];
      if (a < b) {
        var min = toBeSorted[j];
        toBeSorted[j] = toBeSorted[i];
        toBeSorted[i] = min;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is how the above code works :

```
players = ["John", "Jack", "Bob"];
scores = [2, 1, 3];
ranking = [0, 1, 2];
indirectSort(3, ranking, scores);
console.log(ranking);
// [1, 0, 2]
console.log(players[ranking[0]]);
// "Jack"
console.log(scores[ranking[0]]);
// 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a sorted Players array, where each player has a name and a score

```
function main()
            {
                var players = new Array();

                for(i = 0; i<3; i++){
                    let player = {};
                    player.name = prompt("Player " + (i+1) + " : ");
                    player.score = prompt("Score " + (players[i]) + " : ");
                    players[i] = player;
                }

                players.sort(function(a,b){
                     if (a.score < b.score)
                         return -1;
                     if (a.score> b.score)
                          return 1;
                     return 0;
                })

                console.log(players);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following. I am just using `push` of array(for adding an object to array). And for sorting you can use `sort`(for sorting array based on the score) of Array.Prototype. See below code.

```js
var array=[];

function add(){
    var x={};
    x.name=prompt("Player " + (array.length+1) + " : ");
    x.score=parseInt(prompt("Score " + (x.name) + " : "));
    array.push(x);
    array.sort((a,b)=>a.score<b.score)
    console.log(array);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="add()">add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could and should be storing each user as an object in an array like this:

```js
function main(){

    var players = [];
    for(var i = 0;i<3;i++){
      var player = {};
      player.name = prompt("Enter user name");
      var ranking = prompt("Enter user ranking");
      player.ranking = parseInt(ranking);
      players.push(player)
    }
    
    console.log("Players");
    players.forEach(function(player){
      console.log(player.name,player.ranking);
    });
    //Now sort based on ranking
    players = players.sort(function(pA,pB){
      return pA.ranking - pB.ranking;
    });
    players.forEach(function(player){
      console.log(player.name,player.ranking);
    });
} 

main();
```

Comment: You are welcome.May I ask why did you unmark my answer as the correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should use array of objects instead of separate arrays like:

```
let data = [
  {name: 'Jeremy', score: 12},
  {name: 'Julien', score: 18},
  {name: 'Olivia', score: 22}
];
```

You can then sort and print result with `.sort()`:

```js
let data = [
  {name: 'Jeremy', score: 12},
  {name: 'Julien', score: 18},
  {name: 'Olivia', score: 22}
];

data.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score);

console.log(`The first => ${data[0].name} with ${data[0].score} scores`);
console.log(`The second => ${data[1].name} with ${data[1].score} scores`);
console.log(`The third => ${data[2].name} with ${data[2].score} scores`);
```

However if for some reasons you want to stick with 2 arrays, you can also transform both arrays in single array of object and print result.

```js
let players = ['Jeremy', 'Julien', 'Olivia'];
let score = [12, 18, 22];

function printResult(p, s) {
  let a = p.reduce((a, c, i) => (a.push({name: c, score: s[i]}), a), [])
           .sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score);
                 
  console.log(`The first => ${a[0].name} with ${a[0].score} scores`);
  console.log(`The second => ${a[1].name} with ${a[1].score} scores`);
  console.log(`The third => ${a[2].name} with ${a[2].score} scores`);
}

printResult(players, score);
```

**Useful Resources:**

- [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [`Template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)